# Getting rank of element upon sorting the array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, lambda, java-8

I am given an array, and I would like to find the position of these elements in the sorted version of the array. So, the input and output would look like as follows

```
Input : {10, 5, 4, 9, 8, 3, 2, 1,  6, 7}
Output: {0, 3, 4, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7}
```

This means that, 10 would be at 0th position in the sorted array, and 5, would be in the fourth index, ie sortedinput[3].

Here is a one-liner which does it

```
Arrays.sort(index, (a, b) -> (nums[b] - nums[a]));
```

The method would look as follows

```
public Integer[] findIndexInSortedArray(int[] nums) {
        Integer[] index = new Integer[nums.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            index[i] = i;
        }

        Arrays.sort(index, (a, b) -> (nums[b] - nums[a]));

        return index;
}
```

Is there a way, to do the same as above, without using lambdas, and any of the features of Java 8? Is it possible to achieve this, using only a Comparator?

Comment: How is `10` is `0th`? Shouldn't it be `9th`

Comment: @bureaquete That depends on whether the order is descending or ascending. The current lambda expression in the OP's code assumes descending order.

Comment: @Eran then how is `3` is `1st`? His final array is `{10, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9}`

Comment: @bureaquete Where did you get `{10, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9}` from? His final array is `{0, 3, 4, 9, 8, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7}`. 0 is the index of 10 in the original array, 3 is the index of 9, 4 is the index of 8, and so on.

Comment: @Eran oh I see, I though wrongly, I though the output index was identical, and showing final index in sorted array of the same index value in input, sorry.

Comment: so do you just want a sorted array or do you want ranks? I presume you are using the sorted array in conjunction with the original to produce the ranks. That should work fine as long as there aren't any duplicates.

Comment: This code `Arrays.sort(index, (a, b) -> (nums[b] - nums[a]));` can fail if `nums[b]` is very large and `nums[a]` is a negative number. Integer overflow will rear its ugly head. See http://blog.mischel.com/2016/11/21/subtraction-is-not-the-same-as-comparison/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda expression can always be replaced by the functional interface it implements (`Comparator<Integer>` in your case). It just takes longer to write:

```
Arrays.sort(index, new Comparator<Integer> () {
                       public int compare (Integer a, Integer b) {
                           return Integer.compare(nums[b],nums[a]);
                       }
            });
```

Comment: I do not get why this is getting down voted. It is what @saltmangotree asks for, isnt it?

Comment: I'd use `Integer.compare` (which is pre Java 8) considering the overflow issue with a naive subtraction.

Comment: @Eran, I understand the solution, but have a follow up question. When does the Comparator know when to stop the process of sorting. Is it when for the given array, which is index, it has ensured that for any two Integer a and b passed in, nums[b] is always greater than nums[a] ? What is the order of elements processed for a and b, does it check for all possible paits of a and b? Or is this determined by the sorting algorithm that Arrays.sort internally uses?

Comment: @saltmangotree The Comparator knows nothing. It's the sorting algorithm that makes these decisions.  Any decent sorting algorithm doesn't check all possible pairs.

Comment: @Eran, can we rephrase that as follows :  The Comparator knows nothing about which two elements are chosen and that is decided by the sorting algorithm. However, what the comparator does know is, given two elements, what should come before what. Am I right in saying so?

Answer (score 1):

The `Comparator<T>` Interface is a `FunctionalInterface` and marked as one with the annotation `@FunctionalInterface`.

Since Java 8 you can use FunctionalInterfaces with Lambda expressions as you did it in the Arrays.sort method.

The Expression can be replaced with a [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) and the Code is blowing up but the result is the same:

```
public Integer[] findIndexInSortedArray(int[] nums)
{
    Integer[] index = new Integer[nums.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        index[i] = i;
    }

    Arrays.sort(index, new Comparator<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer a, Integer b)
            {
                return nums[b] - nums[a];
            }
        });

    return index;
}
```

Comment: You solution using Comparator and overriding the compare method is clear to me. But I have a couple of questions regarding the internal working, if you could kindly answer. When does the Comparator know when to stop the process of sorting. Is it when for the given array, which is index, it has ensured that for any two Integer a and b passed in, nums[b] is always greater than nums[a] ? What is the order of elements processed for a and b, does it check for all possible paits of a and b? Or is this determined by the sorting algorithm that Arrays.sort internally uses?

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea:

1. write your own sorting algorithm
2. at the beginning of the sorting algorithm, create an array that has the same size as the array that is to be sorted and is filled with 0,1,2,3,...
3. adjust your sorting algorithm so that every time it performs an action on the array to be sorted, it does the same action on the new array
4. return the new array instead of the array to be sorted

To elaborate on step 3: If you'd use bubble sort, for example, every time you swap an element i and j within the array to be sorted, you swap the elements in the new array with the same indices